# Extjs Problem with parameters exchange between Controller and View

Tags: extjs, parameter-passing, store

I have a problem when I try to make an exchange of parameters between Controller and View. I am not sure, but probably it concern also the store reading. My goal is to update my global variable "maxShoePrize" in my View from the controller.

in my controller I implemented the function:

```
    beforeInit: function (){
            myStore = Ext.getStore('Shoes');
            if (myStore.getCount() > 0)
            {
              var maxId = myStore.getAt(0).get('shoeprice'); // initialise to the first record's id value.

              myStore.each(function(rec) // go through all the records
              {
                maxId = Math.max(maxId, rec.get('shoeprice'));
                return true;
                }, this);

            }
            console.log("maxId = "+maxId);            
            this.getView().setNum(maxId);
        },
```

and in the view:

```
setNum: function (value) {
            console.log("from controller = "+value);
            this.maxShoePrize=value;
             console.log("this.maxShoePrize = "+this.maxShoePrize);
    },
```

and I made in my view's init a simple console log to check the value of maxShoePrize. By debugging and with the console.log I noticed that:

[image]

so it is like it updates the data too late. how can I solve this problem? I also tried to use fireEvent from the controller but doesn't work. Can be the operation on the store the problem?

Comment: where is your fireevent function written?

Comment: It was instead of this.getView().setNum(maxId). Also the code in the view was a bit different.

Comment: share a fiddle where this behavior can be reproduced

Comment: how can I share it?

Comment: create a sample example on https://fiddle.sencha.com so that the issue can be reproduced